# Too many MAPI connections with Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003

When a user has too many MAPI connections ( current limit 32 ).  Is there a way to close the connections without restarting store.exe ?  The close connection on TCPView doesn't seem to do it.

Also, whats the long term fix(s) ?

The error is below.  Also, I have BES (Blackberry) going and this person has lots of mailboxes open.  Is that likely to cause this?

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   MSExchangeIS
Event Category: General 
Event ID:   9646
Date:       7/30/2009
Time:       9:55:23 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   FOO
Description:
Mapi session "/o=FOO Domain/ou=First Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=BAR USER" exceeded the maximum of 32 objects of type "session".
```

Comment: Update:  TCP view no longer shows the connections, but she still can't connect after restarting the computer.  Is restarting store.exe required after this happens?

Comment: But When I go to the particular store in Exchange System Manager I still see lots of sessions.

Comment: She still had her home computer VPN'd in, I think that did it.

Answer (score 1):

I never encoutered this issue but someone [reported](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvradmin/thread/8232bb10-df19-4d5e-a37d-aa5325fb4623) that granting the user 'view info store status' rights on the mailbox store solved the issue. It may be related also to the max objects opened during mapi session, there's a kb article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;830836&x=9&y=13) covering that point.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  We had this issue in an exchange 2003 environment for the last year or so.  Create a security group and give it this specific permission.  Drop users in the group as necessary as you see them show up in the log.